# Applying a max-width larger than 100%

Tags: css

So, I have a list of `inline-block` list items. They all vary in width, but are always on the same line. The number of list items may also vary, so I can not predict the width of the list as a whole. The list should always be centered in its parent container, but when the width exceeds 100%, it should gain a horizontal scroll rather than extending over two lines.

Now, as far as I understand, if I set the `width` to `auto`, it is actually set to `shrink-to-fit` – essentially meaning `max-width: 100%;`, which is not what I want.

Is there a way for me to achieve this reliably with CSS alone?

**Markup**

```
<div>
  <ul>
    <li>Banana</li>
    <li>Krypton</li>
    <li>Molten boron</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
div {
  overflow-x: auto;
  width: 500px;
}
ul {
   max-width: 5000px; /* Doesn't override */
   width: auto; /* Calculated to 500px or less */
}
li { display: inline-block; }
```

It should be noted that this is a responsive layout, so the width of the container is not exactly fixed, but I'm not afraid of manual labour.

My JS Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/TheNix/gdRaB/

My question is similar to [CSS dynamic width larger than 100%](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6042327/css-dynamic-width-larger-than-100) except my child elements are not floated, ergo still in the flow (I have control over this).

Regarding `width: auto;` in the spec: http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/visudet.html#inline-replaced-width

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unless I misunderstood your question, you can simply add `white-space: nowrap;` to your `ul` ([fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/gdRaB/11/)). Then you'll get the desired horizontal scrollbar upon overflow.

[**Edit**]: and `text-align: center;` to your `div` ([fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/gdRaB/12/))

Comment: Ah, of course! And it does work in my specific scenario. Cheers.

Comment: Also, I think you can remove most of the styling on the `ul` http://jsfiddle.net/gdRaB/16/

Answer (score 1):

I think what you want is min-width, not max-width

```
ul {
   **min-width: 5000px;** /* Doesn't override */
   width: auto; /* Calculated to 500px or less */
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/gdRaB/5/

Comment: Ah, no, not exactly. The number of list elements and their calculated widths may vary greatly. If there are only a few items, I don't want a 5000px wide scroll. The `max-width` in my example has no function, I simply wanted to illustrate that `width:auto` can't be wider than its parent.

Answer (score 0):

http://jsfiddle.net/gdRaB/10/

I put the div in a container div

```
<div class="container">
<div class="list">
    <ul>
        <li>Banana</li>
        <li>Molten Boron</li>
        <li>Steak sauce</li>
        <li>Unicorn tears</li>
        <li>Ground-up griffins</li>
        <li>Semi-alive hobgoblins (frozen)</li>
    </ul>
    </div>
</div>



.container{
    width: 500px;
    overflow: auto;}

.list{
    width: 5000px;
}

ul {
    width: 5000px;
    overflow: visible;
    width: auto;
    display: inline-block;
}

li {
    background: #ccc;
    display: inline-block;
    margin: 0 5px;
    padding:2px 5px;
}​
```

​